# How Access FooterText (Telerik-RadGrid) In A DetailTable In CodeBehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, footer, radgrid

I have a Telerik RadGrid in my asp.net web form Like Below :

```
MasterTableView
           DetailTables -> GridTableView
```

in that detail Table i have a column like below:

```
                            <telerik:GridTableView runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID,Customer_ID,CardType_ID,OrderStatus_ID"
                                DataSourceID="sdsOrders" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
                                AllowMultiColumnSorting="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="True" OnDataBinding="GridTableView_DataBinding">  
...   

                            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalPrice" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter TotalPrice column"
                                HeaderText="TotalPrice" SortExpression="TotalPrice" 
                                UniqueName="TotalPrice" AllowFiltering="False" FooterText="Sum: " Aggregate="Sum">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="100px" />
                            </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

i want to change the color of footertext(Sum) and that (Sum) in footer.
for DataBoundColumns in MasterTableView the codes below work:

```
protected void GridTableView_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridBoundColumn TotalPrice = grdCustomers.MasterTableView.GetColumnSafe("TotalPrice") as GridBoundColumn;
    TotalPrice.FooterAggregateFormatString = "<span class=\"AggregateTitleColor\">Sum : </span>" + "{0:#,0 ;#,0- }";
    TotalPrice.FooterStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("blue");
}
```

now how can i re-write those codes for that TotalPrice in DetailTable?

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you utilizing the DetailTableDataBind event handler anywhere?

Comment: Also, In the ItemDataBound event handler, you can catch cases where e.Item.ItemType is Footer and style at that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer:
first should use DataBinding in MasterTableView.
and re-write codes like this :

```
protected void MasterTableView_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)  <- Pay Attention Here
{
    GridBoundColumn TotalPrice = grdCustomers.MasterTableView.DetailTables[0].GetColumnSafe("TotalPrice") as GridBoundColumn;
    TotalPrice.FooterAggregateFormatString = "<span class=\"AggregateTitleColor\">Sum : </span>" + "{0:#,0 ;#,0- }";
    TotalPrice.FooterStyle.ForeColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("blue");
}
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Have a peek at the documentation for [Totaling in RAD Grid](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-totals-in-footers.html) controls.I realise you already know how to get the total to appear, however there's a nice chunk of C# and ASP code there that shows the changing of footer colors using the FooterStyle attribute.

Comment: thanks for the answer / but in those samples there is no DetailTable!